# regular expression to strip leading characters up to first encountered digit

Tags: regex, r

I have a string titled thisLine and I'd like to remove all characters before the first integer. I can use the command

```
regexpr("[0123456789]",thisLine)[1]
```

to determine the position of the first integer. How do I use that index to split the string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer:

```
sub('^\\D*', '', thisLine)
```

where

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `\\D` matches any non-digit (it is the opposite of `\\d`)
- `\\D*` tries to match as many consecutive non-digits as possible

Comment: Nice! I forgot that escape-capitals represent the negation of their lowercase counterparts.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Could you explain how that regular expression works?

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here if you are still able to help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003568/extract-first-number-from-string

Answer (score 7):

My personal preference, skipping `regexp` altogether:

```
sub("^.*?(\\d)","\\1",thisLine)
#breaking down the regex
#^ beginning of line
#. any character
#* repeated any number of times (including 0)
#? minimal qualifier (match the fewest characters possible with *)
#() groups the digit
#\\d digit 
#\\1 backreference to first captured group (the digit)
```

Comment: +1 for breaking it down, I appreciate it. Regex is still mystical for me!

Comment: Once you get them, regular expressions are fun! Find & replace can get a lot easier. And of course, think of the [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/208/).

Answer (score 6):

You want the `substring` function.

Or use `gsub` to do work in one shot:

```
> gsub('^[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]', '', 'abc1def')
[1] "def"
```

You may want to include that first digit, which can be done with a capture:

```
> gsub('^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]])', '\\1', 'abc1def')
[1] "1def"
```

Or as flodel and Alan indicate, simply replace "all leading digits" with a blank.  See flodel's answer.

Comment: You beat me to `sub`/`gsub`. My only addition is that you'll want the `*` to be non-greedy if you use `gsub`: `gsub('^.*?([[:digit:]])', '\\1', 'abc1def')`

Comment: You don't need a non-greedy quantifier **or** a capturing group.  Just replace `'^[^[:digit:]]*'` with nothing.