# Extract first number from string

Tags: regex, r

I have a string, thisLine, which contains 11 numbers separated by spaces. I want to obtain just the first number. I tried the command:

```
grep('\\d*\\.\\d*',thisLine,value=TRUE)
```

It returns the entire string, not the first number. How do I return just the first number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sure there are plenty of possibilities, here are a few I would consider:

```
thisLine <- paste(runif(11), collapse = " ")
thisLine
# [1] "0.841216114815325 0.861485596280545 0.973681036382914 0.683699210174382 0.95226536039263 0.368689567316324 0.173984130611643 0.497511914698407 0.870743532432243 0.45606177020818 0.222731305286288"

sub("\\s+.*", "", thisLine)              # assumes no leading space
sub("\\s*(\\S+?)\\s.*", "\\1", thisLine) # handles leading spaces
strsplit(thisLine, " ")[[1]][1]          # more flexible if you want 2nd, 3rd, ...
```

All give

```
# [1] "0.841216114815325"
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using strsplit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very nicely with the `str_first_number()` function from the `strex` package.

```r
library(strex)
johnsmith <- "John Smith, 34 years of age, 6ft tall, 85kg."
str_first_number(johnsmith)
#> [1] 34
str_nth_number(johnsmith, n = 1)  # first number
#> [1] 34
str_nth_number(johnsmith, n = 2)  # second number
#> [1] 6
str_nth_number(johnsmith, n = -1)  # last number
#> [1] 85
str_last_number(johnsmith)
#> [1] 85
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).